# How to add an extra column to a current matrix (list)?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

```
a = {{-800, 1712}, {-801, 1713}, {-806, 1832}}
TableForm[a]
b = a[[All, 2]] - Min[a[[All, 2]]]
```

How do I make a new matrix (list) whic looks like this

```
-800  1712 0
-801  1713 1
-806  1832 120
```

The 3rd column, takes the difference between the value from the 2nd column and it's minimum of the whole 2nd column.

I tried to `Join` the two, but with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps I've missed something, but you seem to just want to append a vector (which you have already calculated) to a matrix.

Documentation for `Append[]` shows how to do it:

[image]

For your case since you already have `a` and `b`:

```
MapThread[Append, {a, b}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

A different approach enables you to join matrixes to make longer rows:

The following makes a 2 column matrix from your b

```
b2 = Transpose[{b, b}];
b2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The documentation for `Join[]` shows the way to do what you asked for in your comment:

[image]

Note that the 2 at the end of the `Join[]` operates as a level specification.

For your case:

```
Join[a, b2, 2];
% // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: How would I `Append` two columns? Do I have to use `MapThread[Append, { MapThread[Append, {a, b}], b} ] // TableForm`, or there is an easy way? Thanks.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu - see addition to the answer.