# Add elements of one list to sublists of another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list of sublists with different lengths `{{1,1,1},{2,2},{3,3,3,3}}` and a second list `{4,5,6}`with the same number of elements as I have sublists in the first list.

I would like to add the elements of the second list as last elements to each sublist. The result should look like this: `{{1,1,1,4},{2,2,5},{3,3,3,3,6}}`

I am looking for a beginner solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This topic has the answer: [67423](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67423/5478). It is marked as a duplicate but I don't think the latter one fits here.

Comment: you may try `MapThread[Append, {{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}}, {4, 5, 6}}]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
sublists = {{1,1,1},{2,2},{3,3,3,3}}
list = {4,5,6}
Map[Flatten,Transpose@{sublists,list},{-3}] (* inline-edit: please, please, don't use this *)
(* {{1,1,1,4},{2,2,5},{3,3,3,3,6}} *)
```

Not too great, especially if the elements are non-atomic expressions.

```
Map[Flatten,Transpose@{sublists,list},{1}]
```

or

```
Flatten/@(Transpose@{sublists,list})
```

seems a safer solution.

Or with `Append`:

```
Append@(Evaluate@(Sequence@@#))&/@Transpose@{sublists,list}
```

I'm still wondering, how to get rid of that `Transpose` without a loss of the functional approach.

**EDIT** of course, silly me, I've overlooked `MapThread` as provided in the linked question.

```
MapThread[Append,{sublists,list}]
```

**EDIT2** some benchmarking.

```
sublists = RandomReal[5, {10*^5,5}];
list = RandomInteger[5,10*^5];

First@Timing@MapThread[Append,{sublists,list}]
(* 1.154407 *)

First@(Timing@(Append@(Evaluate@(Sequence@@#))&/@Transpose@{sublists,list}))
(* 3.057620 *)

First@Timing@(Flatten/@Transpose@{sublists,list})
(* 2.012413 *)
```

Obviously `MapThread` (as also provided now in the comments) is the way to go.

**More options**

As in my first two approaches `Flatten` performed better than `Append`, I figured, there must be a better way.

```
First@Timing@MapThread[Flatten[{##}]&, {sublists,list}]
(* 2.589617 *)
```

(deleted approach with `Join`, as it was incorrect, corrected version doesn't improve speed, will look for other fast methods)