# Combining a list with a certain index of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists. One with three levels (list) and a second one (list 2)

```
list = {{{2, 0}, {2, 3}}, 
        {{5, 3}, {4, 0}},
        {{0, 5}, {0, 0}}}
list2 = {1,2,3}
```

and I want to combine the pairs of each second level from list  with list2 to get

```
listcombined = {{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}, 
                {{2, 5, 3}, {2, 4, 0}},
                {{3, 0, 5}, {3, 0, 0}}}
```

Right now I used `Map Indexed`with the following function and got

```
combine [x_,index_]:={list2[[[index[1]]]],x}
MapIndexed [combine,list,{2}]

{{{{1, {2, 0}}, {1, {2, 3}}}, 
  {{2, {5, 3}}, {2, {4, 0}}},
  {{3, {0, 5}}, {3, {0, 0}}}}
```

To get the desired list I then use first `Flatten` and two times `Partition`.
Is there also an easier way, which avoids the last three steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a direct way using `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[Prepend[#, list2[[#2[[1]]]]] &, list, {2}]
```

and another way using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[list, {i_, _, 0} :> ({list2[[i]], ##} &)]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you reshape `list2` to have the same depth as `list`, you can `Join` them directly at the deepest level:

```
Join[
 Map[List, Transpose @ ConstantArray[list2, {2}], {2}],
 list,
 3
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I might start with MapThread. Let's see what we get with a dummy function:

```
MapThread[f, {list, list2}]
(* {f[{{2, 0}, {2, 3}}, 1], f[{{5, 3}, {4, 0}}, 2], f[{{0, 5}, {0, 0}}, 3]} *)
```

So, we've reduced the problem to defining f in a way that prepends its second argument to every member of its first argument. We could do something like this:

```
PrependToEach[list_, elem_] := Prepend[elem] /@ list
```

Combine these into:

```
MapThread[PrependToEach, {list, list2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[list1, list2];

list1 = {{{2, 0}, {2, 3}}, {{5, 3}, {4, 0}}, {{0, 5}, {0, 0}}};
list2 = {1, 2, 3};

Transpose[{List /@ list2, list1}]

> {{{1}, {{2, 0}, {2, 3}}}, {{2}, {{5, 3}, {4, 0}}}, {{3}, {{0, 5}, {0, 
>     0}}}}
```

Now use `Thread`:

```
res = Thread[Join[First@#, Transpose@Last@#]] & /@ 
  Transpose[{List /@ list2, list1}]

MatrixForm /@ {list2, list1, res}

listcombined == res (*True*)
```

[image]

---

Another solution using `Table`:

```
res2 = Table[
  Prepend[#, list2[[i]]] & /@ list1[[i]], {i, 1, Length@list1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, the following puzzle in the form of code works:

```
ArrayReshape[Map[Flatten@Append[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, Level[Map[Thread, Thread[Map[Composition[Transpose, List, ConstantArray[#, Mean[Map[Length, list, {1}]]] &], list2] -> list]], {Mean[Map[Length, list, {1}]]}]], MapAt[# + 1 &, Dimensions[list], Last[list2]]]
```

The result:

[image]

Or more simple using `Table`:

```
Table[Prepend[list[[i, j]], list2[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list2]}, {j, 1,Mean[Map[Length, list, {1}]]}]
(*{{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2, 5, 3}, {2, 4, 0}}, {{3, 0, 5}, {3, 0, 0}}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayFlatten[{#}] & /@ Thread[{list2, list}]



(* {{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2, 5, 3}, {2, 4, 0}}, {{3, 0, 5}, {3, 0, 0}}} *)


% ==listcombined

True
```

**Edit**

Because this method is almost identical to a [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159764/106) answer of mine, I've marked it 'community wiki'. Feel free to edit

Answer (score 2):

There are also some nifty padding functions, the best one for this case might be ArrayPad. To use it, we need to manipulate list2 into the right form:

```
ArrayPad[list, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}, List@*List /@ list2]
```